# Remove outer quotes with preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have following lines in my file:

```
normal line    
"line in quotes"
line with "quoted" word
line with quotes word at "end"
"quoted line with quoted word at "end""
```

I need to remove only outer quotes.

Result:

```
normal line    
line in quotes
line with "quoted" word
line with quotes word at "end"
quoted line with quoted word at "end"
```

Can this be done with one `preg_replace()`?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
$result = preg_replace('~^"((?:[^"\r\n]+|"[^\r\n"]*")*+)"$~m', '$1', $text);
```

pattern details:

```
~                    # pattern delimiter
^                    # anchor for the begining of the line
"                    #
(                    # open the capture group 1
    (?:              # non-capturing group, content of a line between quotes:
        [^"\r\n]+    #    - all that is not a quote or a newline
      |              # OR
        "[^\r\n"]*"  #    - a substring between quotes
    )*+              # repeat the group zero or more times
)                    # close the capture group
"                    #
$                    # anchor for the end of the line
~m                   # multiline modifier to change ^ and $
```

Answer (score 0):

Preg_replace does not have an "if" sort of thing to say "If there is a quote at the beginning and end." So, you have to express both possibilities:

```
$r = preg_replace('/^"(.*)"$|^(.*)$/', '$1$2', $b);
```

The left of the | matches a line with " at the beginning and end. $1 is the text between. If it doesn't match, $1 is null. The right side of the | matches anything else with $2 being what is in there. It won't go to the right side if the left side matched.